# How to programmatically create a topic in Apache Kafka using Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python, kafka-topic

So far I haven't seen a python client that implements the creation of a topic explicitly without using the configuration option to create automatically the topics.

Answer (score 82):

You can programmatically create topics using either [`kafka-python`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html) or [`confluent_kafka`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) client which is a lightweight wrapper around [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka).

---

**Using [`kafka-python`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html)**

```
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient, NewTopic


admin_client = KafkaAdminClient(
    bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092", 
    client_id='test'
)

topic_list = []
topic_list.append(NewTopic(name="example_topic", num_partitions=1, replication_factor=1))
admin_client.create_topics(new_topics=topic_list, validate_only=False)
```

---

**Using [`confluent_kafka`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python)**

```
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, NewTopic


admin_client = AdminClient({
    "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"
})

topic_list = []
topic_list.append(NewTopic("example_topic", 1, 1))
admin_client.create_topics(topic_list)
```

Comment: could you add topic configuration e.g max.message.bytes=1000000 example for confluent_kafka

Comment: Using the above technique I'm able to create Topic(s), I get the response {'jjd_topic1': <Future at 0x7f7914970940 state=running>} but when I then List the topics the new topic is not in the list... it's like it doesn't persist it.   What could be happening here?

Comment: I also see no new topic in kafka here as a result by using the confluent_kafka answer.

Comment: I also saw similar issue, but once you produce a message on that topic, it starts showing up. 
`
from confluent_kafka import Producer
producer = Producer({
"bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"
    })
    producer.produce("example_topic", key='key1', value='value1')
    producer.flush()
`

Comment: Is there way to create topic using kafka default properties? I mean without explicitly mentioning partitions and replication factor!

Comment: @JamesD i think you need to wait for the operation to finish. See Basic AdminClient Example https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python#basic-adminclient-example

Answer (score 11):

If you can run `confluent_kafka` (Python) `v0.11.6` or above, then the following is how to `create kafka topics`, `list kafka topics` and `delete kafka topics`:

```
>>> import confluent_kafka.admin, pprint

>>> conf        = {'bootstrap.servers': 'broker01:9092'}
>>> kafka_admin = confluent_kafka.admin.AdminClient(conf)

>>> new_topic   = confluent_kafka.admin.NewTopic('topic100', 1, 1)
                  # Number-of-partitions  = 1
                  # Number-of-replicas    = 1

>>> kafka_admin.create_topics([new_topic,]) # CREATE (a list(), so you can create multiple).
    {'topic100': <Future at 0x7f524b0f1240 state=running>} # Stdout from above command.

>>> pprint.pprint(kafka_admin.list_topics().topics) # LIST
    {'topic100' : TopicMetadata(topic100, 1 partitions),
     'topic99'  : TopicMetadata(topic99,  1 partitions),
     'topic98'  : TopicMetadata(topic98,  1 partitions)}
```

And to `delete kafka topics` using that same `kafka_admin` object, this:

```
kafka_admin.delete_topics(['topic99', 'topic100',]) # DELETE
```

I hope this helps. **\(◠﹏◠)/**

Comment: P.S. Where possible, I prefer the `confluent_kafka` library to the `kafka-python` library because the former is a "thin wrapper" (quoting the Confluent literature) over the `librdkafka C/C++ library`; and therefore performant. Though, in fairness, `kafka-python` is more Pythonic and both libraries work well.

Comment: When I open a python shell and I type your code in line for line it works 100% - I create the topic and when I list all topics it it there. But when I put it in a .py file and run the file, for some reason it does not create even though it does not give an error. If I copy every line in the file, and paste it into a python shell, then it creates again. The exact same code works in the shell but not in a file...

Comment: @AlfaBravo Hmmm... Are you sure the program is running at all? Try inserting `print('hello')` statements around the code to check.

Comment: Yes, I have experienced that first hand - the program runs, and the client returns information about the topics that got created {'jjd_topic1': <Future at 0x7f7914970940 state=running>}, but when I run the list, they are not there.   Like they never got committed.   Why would that be?

Comment: Super bizarre -- @AlfaBravo I am experiencing the same issue. If I run as a .py file it doesn't create the topic, but If I go into a python shell and do it it gets created...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can can use the following to ensure that your topic already exist (I assume you are using the following [kafka python](https://github.com/mumrah/kafka-python) implementation):

```
client = KafkaClient(...)
producer = KafkaProducer(...)
client.ensure_topic_exists('my_new_topic')
producer.send_messages('my_new_topic', ...)
```

Comment: That won't work. `ensure_topic_exists` only works with the auto topic creation enabled. https://github.com/mumrah/kafka-python/blob/cd81cf0ec8c1b7e7651374c5d1cbd105d003d352/kafka/client.py#L305-L306

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no kafka server api to create a topic so you have to use topic automatic creation of the or the command line tool:

```
bin/kafka-create-topic.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replica 1 --partition 1 --topic test
```

Comment: No. You use the AdminClient per NYCeyes's comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's already too late. I don't know about a command for explicit creation of the topics but the following creates and adds the messages.

I created a python kafka producer:

```
prod = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
for i in xrange(1000):
    prod.send('xyz', str(i))
```

In the list of Kafka topics `xyz` was not there previously. when I did the above method, the Python-kafka client created it and added the messages to it.

Comment: Actually the broker created the topic and only because auto.topic.create.enable was set to "true". All topics created this way will have the default configuration with may or may not be good for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
topic = 'topic-name'

producer.send(topic, final_list[0]).get(timeout=10)
```

Comment: What is `final_list`?

Comment: @BorisTsema

Please refer: https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/master/kafka/producer/kafka.py#L516

It's a topic value, if I'm not wrong.
The data that you want to send to consumer.

Answer (score 0):

The AdminClient API needed to do programmatic topic creation and configuration was just added in Kafka 0.11 (initially for Java)

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-117%3A+Add+a+public+AdminClient+API+for+Kafka+admin+operations

It is expected that non-Java client libraries will add this functionality as well over time. Check with the author of the Kafka Python client you are using (there are several) to see if and when KIP-4 admin protocol support will be in the API

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-4+-+Command+line+and+centralized+administrative+operations